# Wake on lan with Easybox & IPv6

Tags: router, port-forwarding, ipv6, wake-on-lan, teamviewer

Currently I am using TeamViewer to control a remote pc. Now I also want to be able to start that pc remotely. I was thinking about using the TeamViewer Wake on Lan fuctionality, but any other solution to start the pc is welcome as well.

My problem is configuring my network/router, since it seems to lack any port forwarding options.

**More details about my network:**

This computer sits behind a Vodafone Easybox. I think the model is the Easybox 803.

**This is what I tried:**

My initial though was to configure my router to forward any package on a specific port to the desired pc via its local IP.

Since I do not have a static IP, I configured a dynamic DNS address to be able to reach my router from anywhere.
I was able to configure DynDNS, so it leads to router (only IPv4 though).

I cannot configure any port forwarding in the router though, which left me stuck there. My research suggests, that port forwarding got removed for IPv6 - so I guess I am only sharing this IPv4 address with others.
Now I am wondering how this could be configured.

I was wondering if IPv6 helps, since IPv6 addresses are globaly unique, but pinging the PC's IPv6 did not work from an external network. (The router has a firewall option (on or off). Turning it off did not help.)

What do I have to configure since the router does not support port forwading since IPv6?

Comment: You mention _wake on lan_ in the title and then talk about a lot of other things. How is IPv6 related to your question. What do you want to do? Do you want to remotely wake up your computer? You might want to make your question clearer, to maybe get some answers.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani My issue is to configure my network, so the package reaches the remote pc. I was thinking IPv6 might help in that regard. I udated the question and hope its more understandable now.

Comment: Thanks for trying, please note that the title is still pretty misleading (wake-on-lan having nothing to do with the post and being present in the tags too). Just as with news, people will see the title and decide to know more about the answer or let it go. With that title and tags, people that could actually help, have probably driven by.

Answer (score 0):

If your router does not allow port forwarding, then there is no way it will relay IPv4 packets to your computer, but note that some routers expose the forwarding via UPnP.

You can check if that is the case by installing and UPNP client. An example for Debian: you install `miniupnpc` and then do something like:

```
$ upnpc -a YOUR_LOCAL_IP 8080 8080 tcp 0
```

that will forward from YOUR_PUBLIC_IP:8080 to YOUR_PRIVATE_IP:8080

You can check if your router speaks UPNP (and the current mappings) with this:

```
$ upnpc -l
```

IPv6 could help if, and only if, your provider is assigning a (public) prefix to you and the router allows for direct communication.

There are many other ways to reach in, such as Teredo, an outgoing generic tunnel, a TOR service ... even a combination of those, but that's outside the scope of the question.